# how to update a table when the where clause's value has more than 32 characters in module of proc SQL of SAS enterprise guide

Tags: sas

here is the scenario: at the beginning, I prepare to import a csv file; then in Proc SQL, I insert  the record of temp data set into database, the following are my difficulties:

for the sake of audit, I want to update one record in a table in the database to record this insert operation:

```
update table1 
set inserted_record=&SQLOBS, insert_date=today() 
where filename=&csv_file_name;
```

But the length of the filename is more than 32 character.what should I do ? Thanks!

My SAS code is like the following:

```
DATA Temp1;
```

File_name="kkkkkkkkkkk_product_information_20200101_20211005_FULL.csv"
run;

Data work.temptable;
length
Product_ID $36
Worth_USD  $9;
Format
Product_ID  Char36.
Worth_USD   Char9.;
Informat
Infile
input
Run;

Libname lib1 Teradata user=userid Password=xxxxxx

proc SQL;
insert into lib1.table1(col1,col2)
select prodcut_id,worth_usd from work.temp_table;
update lib1.import_summary set inserted_record=&sqlobs,operated_date=today() where file_name='&file_name';
Run;

according to the log, the SAS code can do the insert operation successfully while the update operation is not (the log shows "No rows were updated"). I check the table of import_summary, there is already a record whose file_name is "kkkkkkkkkkk_product_information_20200101_20211005_FULL.csv". It should be updated. Who can provide the comments? Thanks!

Comment: Length of the name doesn't matter here, you most likely need it in quotes though.

Answer (score 1):

From your code shown this shouldn't affect anything, you do need to have quotes around the file name as it's likely a character field but the 32 char limit is only on data set names which this is not and the file name doesn't have a 32 character limit.

```
update table1 
set inserted_record=&SQLOBS, insert_date=today() 
where filename="&csv_file_name";
```

EDIT:
This needs double quotes, not single quotes:

```
 where file_name='&file_name';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me elaborate my issue. Please see my original post, I have changed it.

Comment: Have posted the SAS code, expect to your comments. Thanks!

Comment: The code posted doesn't do anything at all. You reference a CSV file but don't read anything from it in the data step, so you don't create any data there. If I assume this is just skeleton code, then the issue is that macro variables don't resolve in single quotes either. You need to use double quotes as in my example.

Comment: thanks for your comments! According to your comments, I change the single quotes to be double quotes, it does not work.  "&csv_file_name" bring the value of  CSV_file_name, instead of kkkkkkkkkkk_product_information_20200101_20211005_FULL.csv.

Comment: Then you've passed the wrong information to the macro variable. Make sure it has the correct file reference, there's no way I can know that information. And you should at minimum show your code.

Comment: Your code doesn't show you've created the macro variable. Did you test it with a non macro variable first?

Comment: why I need to use a macro variable? I solved this issue by myself. I modified the where clause: update table1 
set inserted_record=&SQLOBS, insert_date=today() 
where insert_time=today();

Comment: The use of macro variable was your approach.